# 2D function to Matrix of values

Tags: evaluation

I am trying to evaluate a function (2D) with specific points. I do this 
 `Usolz = x t;
xrange = Range[0, 1, 0.1];
trange = Range[1, 5, 1];
MatrixForm[(Usolz /. x -> xrange) /. t -> trange]`

but the output has only one ZERO as the first value. I need to have 5 zeros for trange values. Also I would like to have trange values as the first row  and xrange as the first column (for reference purposes)in the output.

Thank you 
Erdem

Comment: Define `Usolz[x_, t_]` and use `Array` or `Table`. Notice that `0. t` is `0.` so you can't replace there further.

Comment: I am aware because it evaluates to zero, I am trying to avoid that.

Comment: Usolz[x_, t_] := x t; uAll=Table[Usolz[x, t], {x, 0, 1, 0.2}, {t, 0, 5, 1}]; MatrixForm[uAll] gives you the desired form.